# Which Datanucleus logging level is the most all-encompassing?

Tags: java, spring, logging, datanucleus

```
DataNucleus.JDO - All messages general to JDO
DataNucleus.JPA - All messages general to JPA
DataNucleus.Persistence - All messages relating to the persistence process
DataNucleus.Query - All messages relating to queries
DataNucleus.Lifecycle - All messages relating to object lifecycle changes
DataNucleus.Cache - All messages relating to the DataNucleus Cache
DataNucleus.ClassLoading - All exceptions relating to class loading issues
DataNucleus.MetaData - All messages relating to MetaData
DataNucleus.Management - All messages relating to Management
DataNucleus.General - All general operational messages
DataNucleus.Connection - All messages relating to Connections.
DataNucleus.JCA - All messages relating to Connector JCA.
DataNucleus.Transaction - All messages relating to transactions
DataNucleus.Plugin - All messages relating to DataNucleus plug-ins
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration - All messages relating to value generation
DataNucleus.Datastore - All general datastore messages
DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema - All schema related datastore log messages
DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist - All datastore persistence messages
DataNucleus.Datastore.Retrieve - All datastore retrieval messages
DataNucleus.Datastore.Native - Log of all 'native' statements sent to the datastore
DataNucleus.Enhancer - All messages from the DataNucleus Enhancer.
DataNucleus.SchemaTool - All messages from DataNucleus SchemaTool
DataNucleus.IDE - Messages from the DataNucleus IDE.
```

I'm using `java.util.logging` in a Spring app.

Instead of seeing this format of log output:

```
21:26:09,406 (main) INFO  DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema - Creating table null.DataNucleus_TABLES
```

I just see this:

```
21:26:09,406 Creating table null.DataNucleus_TABLES
```

With so many different options of output to display, I'm including all of them since I can't tell which category I'm looking at. So, what would be the highest level setting to enable so that I just set a single log level for all DataNucleus log categories?

Answer (score 0):

The format of output is down to your logging configuration, that quoted in DN docs is for Log4J (what we use), with a formatter. Set category "DataNucleus" only if you want the same logging level for all categories since it is the parent category